# What causes watch piped text to appear cleanly in a terminal but with special chars in a text file?

Tags: bash, encoding, watch

If I run this command:

```
traceroute -p 80 www.google.com. 2>&1|tee -a ~/tmp/traceroute.log
```

The terminal content and file content are the same, and clean (free of any special characters)

However, if I run this command:

```
watch -n5 "traceroute -p 80 www.google.com." 2>&1|tee -a ~/tmp/watch.log
```

I see this in the terminal:

```
Every 5.0s: traceroute -p 80 www.google.com.            Fri Jan 18 11:27:41 2013

traceroute to www.google.com. (74.125.237.115), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  3.138 ms  3.351 ms  3.349 ms
 2  192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)  5.832 ms  6.043 ms  6.183 ms
 3  lback9.comcen.com.au (203.23.236.9)  31.569 ms  31.949 ms  33.484 ms
 4  core-syd-lns2.comcen.com.au (203.23.236.45)  48.331 ms  48.484 ms  48.720 ms
 5  * * *`
```

and this in the log file (SE code parsing/display chokes on the following):

```
(B)0[?1049h[1;24r[m[4l[H[JEvery 5.0s: traceroute -p 80 www.google.com.[1;57HFri Jan 18 11:27:41 2013[3;1Htraceroute to www.google.com. (74.125.237.115), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
[1B 1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  3.138 ms  3.351 ms  3.349 ms
```

[1B 2  192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)  5.832 ms  6.043 ms  6.183 ms
    [1B 3  lback9.comcen.com.au (203.23.236.9)  31.569 ms  31.949 ms  33.484 ms
    [1B 4  core-syd-lns2.comcen.com.au (203.23.236.45)  48.331 ms  48.484 ms  48.720 ms[8;2H5  * * *
    [1B 6  * * *

I've check my locale settings, and pasted them into `~/.bashrc`

```
~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

and in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANG="$LC_ALL"
export LANGUAGE="$LC_ALLL"
export LC_CTYPE="$LC_ALL"
export LC_NUMERIC="$LC_ALL"
export LC_TIME="$LC_ALL"
export LC_COLLATE="$LC_ALL"
export LC_MONETARY="$LC_ALL"
export LC_MESSAGES="$LC_ALL"
export LC_PAPER="$LC_ALL"
export LC_NAME="$LC_ALL"
export LC_ADDRESS="$LC_ALL"
export LC_TELEPHONE="$LC_ALL"
export LC_MEASUREMENT="$LC_ALL"
export LC_IDENTIFICATION="$LC_ALL"
```

Does anyone have an insight into what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch clears the screen every time it displays new information. It does that with special characters printed to the terminal. In the file, you're just seeing those characters interpreted outright. If you want to see a real mess, try turning on some of watch's other features, like --differences highlighting.

Comment: Hmm, OK so this is not unexpected then? If so, is this a feature of watch or a known bug?

Comment: It's expected behaviour.  There might be an option to make `watch` avoid displaying special (cursor control) characters.

Comment: I doubt it. The cursor control characters are necessary to make watch behave the expected way. I you don't want the cursor control characters, just use a loop like `while sleep 2; do someCommand; done`.